# Software to compute several double integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, math-software

I have several double integrals, about $20$.

One of them, with $C1, C2, x_{iu}, x_{jl}$ being four real constants, is:

$\displaystyle \frac{2}{C_1}\frac{2}{C_2}\int_{x_{jl}}^{x_{iu}}\int_y^{x_{iu}}(x - y)(x - x_{iu})(y - x_{jl})dxdy$

I've managed to compute:

$\displaystyle \int_y^{x_{iu}}(x - y)(x - x_{iu})(y - x_{jl})dx$

$\displaystyle = \frac2{C_1}\frac2{C_2}(y - x_{jl})\left(\frac{x_{iu}^3-y^3}3 - (x_{iu} + y)\frac{x_{iu}^2 - y^2}2 + x_{iu}^2y - y^2x_{iu}\right)$

by hand, but that took me more than 1 hour and thus I won't have enough time to compute all of the $20$ integrals by hand.

That's why I'm looking for a free software that can help me trough the computations of these integrals. Note that all the functions within the $10$ double integrals are polynomial functions.

Comment: Does [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8ahttps://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a) work for you?

Comment: Oh gosh this is super working !! Thanks !! I did know this website, I went on it several years ago and I didn't think that improved that much until being able to compute this kind of integrals, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [Computer Algebra System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system). Most popular commercial ones are Mathematica and Maple.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/calculus-and-analysis/) is a good tool to do such calculations online. The free version has a limit in calculation time but for your problem it is [working](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integal_j%5Eu%20integral_y%5Eu%20(x%20-%20y)%20(x%20-%20u)%20(y%20-%20j)%20dx%20dy).

Comment: Thank you, that is totally working ! @saulspatz would have also merit to be selected on this question as he first posted a similar comment.